# How to connect multiple IP addresses with same port number using TCP/IP client?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, multithreading, asyncsocket

I want to read data from multiple tcp/ip devices. I want to create an application in vb.net or c# which will communicate with multiple devices at a time. How to connect multiple devices at a time? IP addresses as xxx.xx.xx.100, xxx.xx.xx.101, xxx.xx.xx.102, xxx.xx.xx.103, xxx.xx.xx.104, xxx.xx.xx.105, etc and same port number 8000.
I am sending request to connected device & the device gives the response.
I am able to read data from a device. Timer used for checking connection status & polling with 100ms interval. How to connect & polling multiple devices at a time without blocking to other? Please help me.

```
Dim tcpclient As System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient
Dim serverStream As NetworkStream
Dim outStream As Byte()
Dim inStream(8192) As Byte
Dim sendstring As String
Dim client_connected as Boolean = False

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)    Handles Timer1.Tick

    // interval 100ms
    If client_connected = False Then
        tcpclient_1 = New System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient
        tcpclient_1.SendTimeout = 10
        tcpclient_1.ReceiveTimeout = 10

        Try
            tcpclient_1.Connect("xxx.xx.xx.100", 8000)
            client_connected = True
            label1.text = "connected"

            sendstring = "xxxx"
            serverStream = tcpclient_1.GetStream()
            outStream = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes()
            serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length)
            serverStream.Flush()

            Dim responseData As [String] = [String].Empty
            responseData = serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, _
                           CInt(tcpclient_1.ReceiveBufferSize))
            label2.text = responseData 
        Catch ex As Exception
            client_connected = False
            label1.text = "disconnected"
        End Try
    Else
        label1.text = "connected"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: There isn't enough description here to help you. "How to connect multiple devices" can mean many different things.

Comment: Answering your question would take up far too much space and would not fit with this sites Q&A format, can you reformat your question to just be about the specific step you are having trouble solving and we can help you get past that step?

Comment: Do you know about threads?

Comment: A TCPServer can handle many TCPClients the IP is just a part of the clients properties so it knows where to send data to.

Comment: As Bob mentioned above, you need to be more specific.

Comment: I have updated my above post. Please see.

Comment: I am sending request to connected device & the device gives the response. I am able to read data from a device. Timer used for checking connection status & polling with 100ms interval. How to connect & polling multiple devices at a time without blocking to other? Please help me.