# Connect Multiple TCP/IP devices by Creating N Number of Sockets to Connect to N number of IP Addresses

Tags: c#

I would like to connect to multiple TCP/IP devices simultaneously to read or send data by creating N number of sockets to connect to N number of IP addresses. I had written the code as below but it will only create one socket to connect to the first IP address instead of creating 3 sockets to connect to 3 IP addresses. Please help. Thanks.

Similar post : [How to connect multiple IP addresses with same port number using TCP/IP client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371362/how-to-connect-multiple-ip-addresses-with-same-port-number-using-tcp-ip-client/57352849#57352849)

```
Socket[] sockets = new Socket[3];
IPAddress[] ipaddress = new IPAddress[3];
string tempIP = "192.168.1.13";

private void StartClient()
{                        
            try
            {                
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)                
                {
                    sockets[i] = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    ipaddress[j] = IPAddress.Parse(tempIP + (j + 3));

                    remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipaddress[j], port);

                    MessageBox.Show(remoteEP.ToString());

                    var result = sockets[i].BeginConnect(remoteEP, new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), sockets[i]);

                    var success = result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

                    MessageBox.Show(success.ToString());

                    if (!success && ButtonStartScan.Text == "Connected")
                    {                            
                        Thread.Sleep(10000);
                        PortDisconnect();
                        Thread.Sleep(10000);
                        PortConnect();
                        throw new Exception("Failed to connect.");
                    }

                    connectDone.WaitOne(1);                         

                    if (ButtonStartScan.Text == "Disconnected")
                    {                           
                        PortDisconnect();
                    }
                    else
                    {                            
                        stopwatch1.Start();
                        receiveDone.Reset();
                        Receive(sockets[i]);
                        bool poll_check = true;

                        do
                        {
                            if (stopwatch1.ElapsedMilliseconds > 10000)
                            {
                                stopwatch1.Restart();                                    
                                string X5 = "X5";
                                Send_stop(sockets[i], X5);
                                sendDone.WaitOne(1000);

                                for (int row = 0; row < DroneList.Rows.Count; row++)
                                {
                                    TimeSpan timeDiff = DateTime.Now - Convert.ToDateTime(DroneList.Rows[row].Cells["TimeDetected"].Value);
                                    int time = Convert.ToInt32(timeDiff.TotalSeconds);

                                    if (time > dronecounter)
                                    {                                            
                                        DroneList.Rows[row].Cells["Inject"].Style.BackColor = Color.DarkGray;

                                        if (!DroneList.Rows[row].Cells["DroneType"].Value.ToString().Contains("Wifi"))
                                        {
                                            DroneStatus.ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Zoom;
                                            Image img1 = Image.FromFile(@"D:\Image\no_alert.PNG");
                                            DroneList.Rows[row].Cells["DroneStatus"].Value = img1;
                                        }

                                        SignalStrength.ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Zoom;
                                        Image img2 = Image.FromFile(@"D:\Image\no_bar.PNG");
                                        DroneList.Rows[row].Cells["SignalStrength"].Value = img2;

                                        if (DroneList.Rows[row].Cells["Inject"].Value.ToString() == "Stop Distract")
                                        {
                                            if (DroneList.Rows[row].Cells["DroneType"].Value.ToString() == "DJI Phantom 3 STD")
                                            {
                                                DroneList.Rows[row].Cells["Inject"].Style.ForeColor = Color.DodgerBlue;
                                                DroneList.Rows[row].Cells["Inject"].Value = "Inject";
                                                string StopString = "S3";
                                                Send_stop(sockets[i], StopString);
                                                sendDone.WaitOne(1000);                                                    
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                DroneList.Rows[row].Cells["Inject"].Style.ForeColor = Color.DodgerBlue;
                                                DroneList.Rows[row].Cells["Inject"].Value = "Distract";
                                                string StopString = "SD";
                                                Send_stop(sockets[i], StopString);
                                                sendDone.WaitOne(1000);                                                   
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                                if (!sockets[i].Connected)
                                {                                        
                                    for (int row = 0; row < DroneList.Rows.Count; row++)
                                    {
                                        if (DroneList.Rows[row].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor == Color.DarkGray)
                                        {

                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            if (DroneList.Rows[row].Cells["Inject"].Value.ToString() == "Stop Inject")
                                            {
                                                if (DroneList.Rows[row].Cells["DroneType"].Value.ToString() == "DJI Phantom 3 STD")
                                                {
                                                    DroneList.Rows[row].Cells["Inject"].Style.ForeColor = Color.DodgerBlue;
                                                    DroneList.Rows[row].Cells["Inject"].Value = "Distract";
                                                    string StopString = "S3";
                                                    Send_stop(sockets[i], StopString);
                                                    sendDone.WaitOne(1000);
                                                }
                                                else
                                                {
                                                    DroneList.Rows[row].Cells["Inject"].Style.ForeColor = Color.DodgerBlue;
                                                    DroneList.Rows[row].Cells["Inject"].Value = "Distract";
                                                    string StopString = "SD";
                                                    Send_stop(sockets[i], StopString);
                                                    sendDone.WaitOne(1000);
                                                }
                                            }

                                            DroneList.Rows[row].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.DarkGray;
                                            DroneList.Rows[row].Cells["Inject"].Style.BackColor = Color.DarkGray;
                                            DroneList.Rows[row].Cells["Whitelist"].Style.BackColor = Color.DarkGray;

                                            if (!DroneList.Rows[row].Cells["DroneType"].Value.ToString().Contains("Wifi"))
                                            {
                                                DroneStatus.ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Zoom;
                                                Image img1 = Image.FromFile(@"D:\Image\no_alert.PNG");
                                                DroneList.Rows[row].Cells["DroneStatus"].Value = img1;
                                            }

                                            SignalStrength.ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Zoom;
                                            Image img2 = Image.FromFile(@"D:\Image\no_bar.PNG");
                                            DroneList.Rows[row].Cells["SignalStrength"].Value = img2;
                                        }
                                    }

                                    PortDisconnect();
                                    Thread.Sleep(10000);
                                    PortConnect();
                                    Thread.Sleep(10000);                                        
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        while (poll_check);
                        receiveDone.WaitOne();                            
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use a individual TCP socket for each connection/device. It doesn't matter that all devices have the same port, as this is only the port used by the remote device. Your pc will randomly choose a port for the outgoing connection, and you can't (and don't want to) do anything about it.

For example, this is what the communication will look like. The outgoing port really doesn't matter at all:

```
Your PC:4568 --> xxx.xx.xx.100:8000
Your PC:7568 --> xxx.xx.xx.101:8000
xxx.xx.xx.100:8000 --> Your PC:4568
xxx.xx.xx.101:8000 --> Your PC:7568
```

Edit:
If you have a small, fixed number of devices, you can just use multiple sockets like this:

```
Socket client1;
Socket client2;
Socket client3;

client1 = new Socket(IPAddress.Parse("xxx.xxx.xxx.100").AddressFamily, 
SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
client2 = new Socket(IPAddress.Parse("xxx.xxx.xxx.100").AddressFamily, 
SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
client3 = new Socket(IPAddress.Parse("xxx.xxx.xxx.100").AddressFamily, 
SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

remoteEP1 = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("xxx.xxx.xxx.100"), port);
remoteEP1 = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("xxx.xxx.xxx.101"), port);
remoteEP1 = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("xxx.xxx.xxx.102"), port);
```

If you have a bigger number of devices, or the ip addresses change dynamically, it would make sense to create the sockets in a for-loop and write them to an array.

Comment: I tried to use loop to connect multiple IP addresses but only one will be connected and other will be blocked.

Comment: @Max what do you mean blocked?

Comment: If I declared the socket one by one, it would not be feasible for large number of devices

Comment: Can I know how to create the socket in a for-loop and write them to an array so that I can send and receive multiple data from multiple devices simultaneously without blocking each other?

Comment: @John I had updated my code as above but it would not work. It would only create one socket and bind to 1 IP address only instead of creating 3 sockets and 3 IP address at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

This is a Networking problem first and barely even a Programming one. The network classes do not care if the target is on the same computer, the same switch or the Voyager Probes.

Socket and IP adress are a integral pair. You can not seperate them from each other.
Knowing only the sockete would be like only knowing the House Number, but not the street. And the IP adress would be only knowing the street, but not which of the several thousand housenumbers.

Communication goes from one pair of IP/Socket to another pair of IP/Socket. In many cases the socket number can be implied. HTTP request usally target Port 80 on the target IP adress.

If you are mostly doing receiving work with limited communication, you can share a port for multiple clients. Port 80 does so. But if the communicaiton is more complex, it is customary to only use the public port to innitate talking, then to all the heavy lifting on a port specific for this process that you jsut dynamically aquire.